# UIAlert doesn't open any more, Xcode tells me to debug for NSLayoutConstraintToNilAnchor

Tags: swift, xcode, layout

Without changing anything in the view controller or updating to a new Xcode Version, displaying a UIAlertController doesn't work anymore.

Xcode gives me the error message: 
  A constraint factory method was passed a nil layout anchor.  This is not allowed, and may cause confusing exceptions. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintToNilAnchor(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

Now I successfully tried to debug it with the breakpoint given in the error message.

That's what I got:

```
Foundation`_NSLayoutConstraintToNilAnchor:
->  0x1b51342ec <+0>:  pacibsp 
    0x1b51342f0 <+4>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
    0x1b51342f4 <+8>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1b51342f8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x1b51342fc <+16>: add    x29, sp, #0x20            ; =0x20 
    0x1b5134300 <+20>: adrp   x19, 224497
    0x1b5134304 <+24>: ldrb   w8, [x19, #0xd30]
    0x1b5134308 <+28>: tbnz   w8, #0x0, 0x1b5134334     ; <+72>
    0x1b513430c <+32>: adrp   x8, 366
    0x1b5134310 <+36>: add    x8, x8, #0x30a            ; =0x30a 
    0x1b5134314 <+40>: adrp   x9, 196084
    0x1b5134318 <+44>: add    x9, x9, #0x2a8            ; =0x2a8 
    0x1b513431c <+48>: stp    x9, x8, [sp]
    0x1b5134320 <+52>: adrp   x0, 196084
    0x1b5134324 <+56>: add    x0, x0, #0x288            ; =0x288 
    0x1b5134328 <+60>: bl     0x1b5105f6c               ; NSLog
    0x1b513432c <+64>: orr    w8, wzr, #0x1
    0x1b5134330 <+68>: strb   w8, [x19, #0xd30]
    0x1b5134334 <+72>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x1b5134338 <+76>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1b513433c <+80>: add    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
    0x1b5134340 <+84>: retab
```

I have to admit, that this debugging is a bit out of my knowledge.

And that's my Code for displaying the Alert:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
        pickerData = data
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 275)
        let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 275))
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        if let index = data.firstIndex(of: "Std.") {
            pickerView.selectRow(index , inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        }

        vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
            (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            ***

            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        alert.addAction(defaultAction)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

The breakpoint stops obviously on the last line:

```
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
```

This is definitely not a public api and can be broken at any moment (for example now). I recommend not to use it, since it can lead to application removing from AppStore.
I recommending instead of hacking `UIAlertController` implement your own popup or use existing libraries.